# If a vector in a linearly independent list is replaced by a linear combination of itself and one other vector is the result linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-independence

If one vector in a linearly independent list is replaced by a linear combination of itself and one other vector from that list is the resulting list always linearly independent? It seems to me that the answer is yes (as long as some non-zero scalar multiple of that first vector is included in the linear combination).

Consider a linearly independent list $(v_{1},v_{2},v_{3})$

Linear independence means that:
$a_{1}v_{1}+a_{2}v_{2}+a_{3}v_{3}=0$ only if $a_{1}=a_{2}=a_{3}=0$.

If we replace $v_{1}$ with a linear combination of itself and $v_{2}$ our list becomes $(b_{1}v_{1}+b_{2}v_{2}, v_{2}, v_{3})$.

To show that this list is also linearly independent we have to ask if the only linear combination of its elements that equals zero has all-zero coefficients. Which is obviously the case because:
$a_{1}(b_{1}v_{1}+b_{2}v_{2})+a_{2}v_{2}+a_{3}v_{3}=0$ and simply rearranging gets us to ($a_{1}b_{1})v_{1}+(a_{1}b_{2}+a_{2})v_{2}+a_{3}v_{3}=0$ and we already know all those coefficients $=0$. And so as long as $b_{1}\neq0$ then all of our $a$ coefficients must be $0$ so the new list is linearly independent.

Is this correct?

Note: I'm assuming that none of the vectors in the original list are $0$ because we've called that list linearly independent (according to Axler in *Linear Algebra Done Right* 3rd ed. p33 "Every list of vectors in $V$ containing the $0$ vector is linearly dependent.")

For context, I'm trying to generalize from the exercises Axler provides. More specifically, I'm trying to develop some kind of spatial intuition for all of this instead of just relying on rearranging terms and checking off definitions.

Perhaps there are more fundamental tools for describing what's going on here? A way to describe a vector's contribution to the dimension and span of a list that can't be undone by linear combinations with other vectors in that list? Something analogous to degrees of freedom in statistics?

(I'm studying this stuff on my own, so the ability to post and get feedback here has been invaluable!)

Comment: So, what is your answer?  Yes or no?  In other words, are you saying that if one vector in a linearly independent list is replaced by a linear combination of itself and one other vector from that list, the resulting list is **always** linearly independent?  Note that at one point in your argument you said, "as long as $b_1\ne0$ and $b_2\ne0$".

Comment: You only need $b_1\neq 0$; if $b_1\neq 0$, then $b_1v_1+b_2v_2,v_2,v_3$ are linearly independent.

Comment: @David In a pinch I’d say yes — although with the caveat that it does seem necessary to qualify the phrase *linear combination* because it seems that if either $b_{1}$ or both $b$ coefficients are zero then the resulting list is not linearly independent (in one case because we have a duplicate or scalar multiple of $v_{2}$ and in the other because we have a zero vector in the list).

Comment: @David so clearly not *always* unless $b_{1}\neq0$. Is there a better way to phrase this? “Nontrivial linear combination” isn’t accurate, right — because that implies both $b$ terms would be zero? Perhaps something along the lines of: “as long as some non-zero scalar multiple of that vector is included in the linear combination”?

Comment: I’ve updated the question to reflect feedback from David and Arturo in the comments above

Comment: Some things are easy to say in words, some are not so easy.  You could just say that $v_1$ is replaced by $b_1v_1+b_2v_2+\cdots$ with $b_1\ne0$.  BTW are you asking the question, or are you answering a question asked by someone else?  If the latter then you really shouldn't be changing the question in any way.

Comment: Thanks. No it’s not a question that was posed by someone else. I just kept seeing exercises that involved linear combinations of elements from linearly independent lists and I was trying to articulate things to myself in a more generalized way. It seems that certain operations alter lists of vectors in major ways (affecting span, linear independence, dimension) while others don’t. Just trying to make sure I have strong grasp of fundamentals before moving on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ironically the spatial intuition you seek can be supplied by determinants, which Axler banishes to the end of his book. I'll just provide an informal sketch over the base field $\mathbb{R}$, but encourage you to read more elsewhere.

The three linearly independent vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3$ span a $3$-dimensional subspace $U$, to which we can restrict attention. A determinant function $D:U^3\to\mathbb{R}$ on $U$ measures the oriented (i.e. signed) volume $D(u_1,u_2,u_3)$ of the parallelepiped formed by the vectors $u_1,u_2,u_3$ in $U$, relative to some fixed chosen unit volume. One fundamental property of $D$ is that it's invariant under shears, for example:
$$D(u_1+\alpha_2u_2+\alpha_3u_3,u_2,u_3)=D(u_1,u_2,u_3)\tag{1}$$
for any choice of $\alpha_2,\alpha_3\in\mathbb{R}$. This is because the orientation and volume of the parallelepiped determined by $u_1,u_2,u_3$ are unchanged if we move $u_1$ in any direction along the $2$-dimensional "base" spanned by $u_2,u_3$ -- in this case both the "base" and the "height" over the base are unchanged. Of course nothing is special about $u_1$, and similar shear invariance holds for each $u_i$ relative to the others.

Another fundamental property is scaling, for example:
$$D(\alpha_1 u_1,u_2,u_3)=\alpha_1 D(u_1,u_2,u_3)\tag{2}$$
The intution here should hopefully be clear. Note that if $\alpha_1<0$ then the orientation (sign) changes because in this case $\alpha_1u_1$ is on the "other side" of the "base" spanned by $u_2,u_3$ than $u_1$. Again a similar property holds for each $u_i$.

It turns out these properties uniquely characterize $D$ up to the choice of the unit volume (i.e. any other function which also satisfies these properties is just a scalar multiple of $D$). Also, we obtain the important result that *$D(u_1,u_2,u_3)\ne 0$ if and only if $u_1,u_2,u_3$ are linearly independent*. This intuitively makes sense because $u_1,u_2,u_3$ form a non-degenerate parallelepiped (i.e. are not contained in a plane) if and only if $u_1,u_2,u_3$ are linearly independent.

How does all this relate to your problem? Well, we know that $D(v_1,v_2,v_3)\ne 0$ since $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are linearly independent, and by (1) and (2)
$$D(\alpha_1v_1+\alpha_2v_2,v_2,v_3)=\alpha_1 D(v_1,v_2,v_3)$$
If $\alpha_1\ne 0$, then the right-hand side is nonzero, so the left-hand side is nonzero, which by the result above implies that the vectors $\alpha_1v_1+\alpha_2v_2,v_2,v_3$ are linearly independent.

Comment: Hah! Wow. That’s exactly what I was looking for. Guess I should give Axler a fair shot and work through to the end of the book in the order with which he laid things out, but this is certainly good motivation to get to the chapter on determinants. And as you pointed out (in your very clear explanation) it’s far more spatially intuitive and makes perfect sense. (Though I assume there’s also value in the algebra-first approach Axler takes so not giving up on that either!)

Comment: @NAD Axler's book is excellent, but you might be disappointed by his chapter on determinants. Better references are listed at the end of my [video](https://youtu.be/9IswLDsEWFk).